# group validator doesn't impact the form.isValid

Tags: angular, forms, validation

It seems to me that when I create a form group in **angular 5**, like this:

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      control1: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      control2: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
    },
    {
       validator: comparisonValidator(
         'control1'
         'control2',
          this.formGroup)
    });
```

the group validator that I set, in this case named compareControls, does not apply to the form when you check `form.isValid` (only the individual control validators seem to be taken into account).

Any thoughts on how to make the **group validator** (comparisonValidator) impact the form.Valid e.g. validity of the form overall?

```
export function comparisonValidator(control1: string, control2: string, group: FormGroup): ValidatorFn { 
    return (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        if (group && group.controls) {
            const f1 = <AbstractControl>group.get(control1);
            const f2 = <AbstractControl>group.get(control2);

            if (f1.value >= f2.value) {
                return {'case': 'From should be less than To'};
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want valid by formGroup (I recommend using @LuaXD's Answer)https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652053/7291379]

If you want valid by formControl, you can get other FormControl from [formControl.Parent](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#parent)

```js
export function comparisonValidator(control1: string, control2: string): ValidatorFn { 
    return (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const group = c.parent;        
        if (group && group.controls) {
            const f1 = <AbstractControl>group.get(control1);
            const f2 = <AbstractControl>group.get(control2);

            if (f1.value >= f2.value) {
                return {'case': 'From should be less than To'};
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

```html
const myComparisonValidator = comparisonValidator('control1'
         'control2');
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      control1: [null, [
        Validators.required, 
        Validators.minLength(3),
        myComparisonValidator
        ]
      ],
      control2: [
        null, [
          Validators.required, 
          Validators.minLength(3),
          myComparisonValidator
         ]
       ]
    });
```